# RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1) when accessing list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this error when accessing the list of productPriceObj, in this list there are two item but it can only read the [0] not the [1][image]

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look in debugger to see what is the `productPriceObjs`. Probably this is not returning a list.

If it is coming from a `http` response.
Please check if this is not a "json inside json" and if you used `jsonDecode(BODY_RESPONSE)` correctly.

Probably is just a type mistake or something is wrong when you bring the information to Widget. The problem belike is before the `return`.

---

If the above informations not works, you can also `print` the list before try to return. Just for confirm that the supposed list has two items. You can also add this:

```
if (YOUR_LIST.isNotEmpty){
    return YOUR_WIDGET;
}
```

---